# what is the difference between outside the main function and inside?

Tags: c++, function, program-entry-point

So I have seen a program from elsewhere and the declaration is outside from the main function.
Just like this code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int num1, num2;
int *ptr1 = &num1, *ptr2 = &num2;
char operation, answer;
char *ptrop = &operation;

int main(){

}
```

But what I am using right now is inside the main function like  this:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int num1, num2;
    int *ptr1 = &num1, *ptr2 = &num2;
    char operation, answer;
    char *ptrop = &operation;
```

So what is the difference from it?

Comment: outside any function or class scope the variable have global scope. To understand the difference add an function and try using the them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first case variables and pointers are accessible from all other functions in the file (i.e. it has global scope) whereas in the second case it is only accessible from within main.

I will give you a small example.

Local to main,

```
#include <iostream>

void fun();

int main(void) {
  int x;
  fun();
  return 0;
}

void fun() {
  x = 1; // compiler error: x not declared in this scope
}
```

Global,

```
#include <iostream>

void fun();

int x;
int main(void) {
  fun();
  return 0;
}

void fun() {
  x = 1; // compiles as x declared globally
}
```

Answer (score 5):

All variables declared outside of the `main` function will have global scope and static storage duration. Variables declared inside main will have automatic storage duration (allocated on the stack) if no storage specifier is provided and will only be visible inside `main`.